# Asynchronous logging to 2 files

Tags: logging, asynchronous, logback

I want to log asynchronously to 2 files, one for system logging, the other for user actions logging. So far I am logging to 1 file, my config file looks like this:

```
<configuration debug="true">

    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="C:/blah" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{DD/MM/YYYY-HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/log.txt</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.logger.name" level="DEBUG" />

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

And I create a logger like this:

```
public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.logger.name");
```

This works fine, but if I want to log to 2 separate files, do I need to write a second config file? Do I need a second `Logger` object also? I would like to have one configuration and specify which file is logged to on creation of the `Logger` object, is this possible? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I want to log the user action to one file and the system logs to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two file appenders, one for system logging and other for user action logging. File appnder extends `UnsynchronizedAppenderBase`  Hence they are async. No need to create to Logger objects. Here is a example.

```
<appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>c:/kp/kp1.log</file>
        <filter class="com.kp.filters.KPFilter">
        </filter>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
    </root>

    <appender name="fileAppender2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">

        <file>c:/kp/kp2.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d [%thread] %-5level %logger{30} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.kp">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender2" />
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>
```

KPFilters.class

```
public class KPFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
        if(event.getLoggerName() !=null && event.getLoggerName().startsWith("org.kp")){
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
        return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
    }

}
```

If you want to have logs to be written to file generated by your package, you can  use as given below

```
<logger name="com.kp">
        <level value="trace" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileappender2" />
</logger>
```

In worst scenario you can create custom appender by extend `UnsynchronizedAppenderBase` and write custom code to process the error message. Based on the message type or message string you can write business logic to write to file or skip the error message.

```
**EDITED:**
```

You can initialize the log in usual way. For example if you want to log in MyClass.

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOG.warn("Hello");
```

Logback back passes the log instance to both appenders. which will be written to two different files.

Comment: So you mean I don't need to reference the file appenders in `AsyncAppender`? Also how do you initialize the logger in java when logging to the 2 files?

Comment: @Sionnach733 Updated the answer, Yes no need its already async, instead create one more appender for second file

Comment: OK, thanks, i have this working. I should rephrase my question. I want to log the user action to one file and the system logs to the other.

Comment: You can add filters http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html  for each in one accept the all the System logs and deny everything else in another log all useractions and deny everything else

Comment: ok, I understand it now, show how to filter in your answer and i will accept

Comment: @Sionnach733 updated the answer, still a smarter way is to use marker