# Multiple loggers with specific appender for each of the loggers in logback

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, logback, appender

I am using Play framework where logback is default logger engine. I want to log two different activities (`Log in` and `Transaction`) in two separate file for easier tracking. For that I have two appenders and two loggers. Each of the loggers are tagged with specific appender.

```
<appender name="TRANSACTION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
     <fileNamePattern>${application.home}/logs/transaction/transaction-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
     <pattern>%message%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="LOGIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>${application.home}/logs/log-in-record.log</file>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="transaction" level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTION" />
</logger>
<logger name="log-in" level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="LOGIN" />
</logger>
```

I want to log transactional activities through **transaction** logger like `play.Logger.of("transaction").info("Test Transaction Log\r\nHere is another line");` 
and sign in or sign up related activities in **log-in** logger like `play.Logger.of("log-in").info("user X has logged in ...");`

But it's not working. Any ideas?

## Edit

By 'not working' I mean that the same log is being appended to both the logger, not specific to the particular log. E.g. if I call `play.Logger.of("log-in").info("user X has logged in ...");` from my Play code, both the **transaction** and **log-in** loggers are logging *user X has logged in ...* to two different files.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'not working'? No log messages at all?

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth: My edit is below the original post. Thanks for your productive query.

Comment: I was looking at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala but I cannot find the answer. Try the play framework google groups list if you don't get any replies here.

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah - Do you see any differences in behaviour when running your application in development and production modes?

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah: refer this question, which I had answered few days back, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287724/asynchronous-logging-to-2-files/21292394#21292394

Comment: My apologies to all of you. I misunderstood. All my loggers are working. I was confused because `Application` logger is logging everything, even when I called specific logger.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `additivity="false"` to your loggers

```
<logger name="transaction" level="INFO" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="TRANSACTION" />
</logger>
<logger name="log-in" level="INFO" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="LOGIN" />
</logger>
```